# What does "sample minimal CA application" mean?

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl

I'm reading openssl manuals, and in the man openssl-ca I've found a note, that "openssl ca is a sample minimal CA application"
What does it mean? I don't understand.
If it is only a sample, what do I need to use performing CA tasks in a production environment? (It is more complex than CA.pl script)

Comment: `openssl ca` is basically an hand saw, i.e. you can do most things but it takes effort and time. If you need comfort, speed etc you don't want to use a chain saw instead - which is a more specialized tool but lets you do things faster and easier. And similar exist CA tools with more comfort, which scale better, integrate better with the rest of the infrastructure,  etc.  The basic idea behind these is still the same.

Comment: Thanks. So, as far as I can understand: openssl app is not only a sample, it is usable in production environment, although it could be uncomfortable, but the certificates/crls/etc made by it, will be the same as if these was made by another, comfortable tool?

Comment: Correct. It can be used to create "real" certificates etc and not only toy examples.

Comment: Thank you, so I can use it for hobby purposes. But... is there any (open source) software, which can do this in a corporate environment?

Comment: There are [various products which fit this description](https://www.google.com/search?q=enterprise+open+source+CA). But product recommendations are off-topic here.